# Reapply column filters after datasource change or disallow filter reset on datasource change

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is this possible with infragistics winforms 15.2 .net framework 4.0? I notice I am able to get a read only columnFilterCollection object via ultragrid.displaylayout.band(i).columnfilters but can I also set this property such that I am able to apply the same column filters that I have gotten from the getter of said property? Or if that is not possible can I disallow a filter reset on a datasource change?

Upon further research I found two methods which may be of use. Can I use

```
UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).ColumnFilters.CopyTo()

UltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).ColumnFilters.CopyFrom()
```

To achieve this result? An example would be most appreciated.

Comment: Let me understand. If you change the DataSource how do you think that the old filter collection based on previous columns and values is still of any use with the new datasource? Or the new datasource is identical in its schema to the old one?

Comment: What is the DataSource - how is it set?

Comment: @Steve That is determined by us for them to be the same.

Comment: @Plutonix It is set via the datasource property of the ultragrid to a DataTable object.

Comment: We seem to be losing sight of the problem. The goal is to apply the same filtering that we had before a datasource change to the grid after a datasource change has occurred.

Comment: I get cautious when people talk about "resetting" a DataSource - very often it isnt needed at all, so *"we"* are trying to usderstand the context..  If you can use the same filters it sounds like it is the same schema source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Function CopyByValue(ByVal input As Object, ByRef target As Object)
        Dim success As Boolean = True

        target = input

        Return success
End Function


Private _inventoryColumnFilters As Object = Nothing
CopyByValue(grdInventory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).ColumnFilters,_inventoryColumnFilters)  
grdInventory.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).ColumnFilters.CopyFrom(TryCast(_inventoryColumnFilters, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnFiltersCollection))
```

This works. Pretty stupid to have a .CopyTo that doesent have an overload for a ColumnFilterCollection parameter or a copy constructor.

Comment: When I needed to get a ColumnFiltersCollection I just used Clone() and it worked. I didn't need a ByVal function.